# Apache MiNifi- Putelasticsearch

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

i make flow, which process real time data from local server and send relevant data to Elasticsearch. I use Minifi, but when I run MiNifi it returned the following error.
Does anyone know, where is the issue?

Thanks

ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.p.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch5 PutElasticsearch5[id=4ed70cbe-9838-35cd-0000-000000000000] PutElasticsearch5[id=4ed70cbe-9838-35cd-0000-000000000000] failed to process due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.Version; rolling back session: {}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.Version
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.(StreamOutput.java:73)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.BytesStreamOutput.(BytesStreamOutput.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.BytesStreamOutput.(BytesStreamOutput.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.BytesStreamOutput.(BytesStreamOutput.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.builder(XContentBuilder.java:67)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.arrayToParsableString(Setting.java:698)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.lambda$listSetting$26(Setting.java:656)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting$2.getRaw(Setting.java:660)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.get(Setting.java:300)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.(PluginsService.java:164)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.(TransportClient.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearch5TransportClientProcessor.getTransportClient(AbstractElasticsearch5TransportClientProcessor.java:230)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearch5TransportClientProcessor.createElasticsearchClient(AbstractElasticsearch5TransportClientProcessor.java:170)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearch5Processor.setup(AbstractElasticsearch5Processor.java:94)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearch5.onTrigger(PutElasticsearch5.java:177)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1122)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Please see here for how to format questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce its footprint, MiNiFi java only ships with the standard bundle of processors. In order to use the other processors that are present within a standard NiFi deployment in MiNiFi, you need to put the appropriate "nar" file into the "lib" of the MiNiFi deployment.

For "PutElasticSearch" you need "nifi-elasticsearch-nar-.nar" where "" is the version of NiFi that your version of MiNiFi is built off of. Versions 0.4.0 of MiNiFi java uses NiFi 1.5.0.

For more information and a list of the processors that do come bundled with MiNiFi out of the box see the "MiNiFi Java Agent Quick Start" documentation, section "Using Processors Not Packaged with MiNiFi"[1]. For more information on the different versions of MiNiFi correspond to the version of NiFi frameworks, see here[2].

[1] https://nifi.apache.org/minifi/minifi-java-agent-quick-start.html

[2] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MINIFI/MiNiFi+Versioning+and+Toolkit+Compatibility